# How can I find $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln(q_{n+1})}{\ln(q_n)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, continued-fractions

The irrationality measure of a positive real number $x$ can be calculated, if the following limit can be calculated, where $q_n$ are the convergents of the simple continued fraction of $x$.

$$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln(q_{n+1})}{\ln(q_n)}$$

Suppose, I have a formula for the entries of the simple continued fraction. Lets say, $a_n=2^n$, so the continued fraction would be $[2,4,8,16,32,\cdots]$.

> How can I calculate the above limit ? And how can I find out whether it exists ? Is it possible that the values oscillate and that neither the limit exists nor the sequence diverges to $\infty$ ?

I know the reccurence relation $$q_1=1\ , \,q_2=a_2\ ,\ q_n=a_nq_{n-1}+q_{n-2}\ for\ n>2$$

but in general, it will be difficult to find a closed form for $q_n$.

The goal is to find a method to prove special numbers with known continued fraction to be transcendental, for which is enough to show that the above limit is greater than $1$.

Comment: Wolfram alpha gives another formula, for which I need $a_{n+1}$ and $q_n$, but still I have no idea how to find that limit (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html)

Comment: Finding the irrationality measure is generally difficult. What is your sequence $a_n$ (or some examples).

Comment: In particular, I am interested in $a_n=2^{2^n}$. Also interesting would be $a_n=n!$

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut There is no formula only containing the $a_j$, right ?

Comment: Not that I know of. I'll think about it and hope to get back to you later today. Do you have any different representation of your number? It might be possible to find the irrationality measure directly (like one does with Liouville numbers).

Answer (score 3):

Assume $f(n)\leq q_n\leq g(n)$ for some functions $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{g(n)}{f(n)} = C$$

for some real $C$. Then,

$$\frac{\ln(a_{n+1})}{\ln(g(n))} \leq  \frac{\ln(a_{n+1})}{\ln(q_n)} \leq \frac{\ln(a(n+1))}{\ln(f(n))}$$

Since

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{g(n)}{f(n)} = C,$$

we have that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(g(n))}{\ln(f(n))} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(g(n))}{\ln(g(n))+\ln\left(\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\right)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(g(n))}{\ln(g(n))+\ln(C)}.$$

Because $q_n$ is unbounded, $g(n)$ must also be unbounded, so this limit equals $1$. Thus

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(a_{n+1})}{\ln(g(n))} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(a(n+1))}{\ln(f(n))}$$

which must also be equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(a_{n+1})}{\ln(q_n)}$ by the squeeze theorem. So, we get that

$$\mu = 2+\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(a_{n+1})}{\ln(q_n)} = 2+\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(a(n+1))}{\ln(f(n))}.$$

From your definition of $q_n$, we have that, for $n>2$,

$$a_2a_3\cdots a_n \leq q_n \leq a_2(a_3+1)(a_4+1)\cdots (a_n+1).$$

Taking these as $f$ and $g$, we get that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{g(n)}{f(n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{k=3}^{n} \frac{a_k+1}{a_k} = \prod_{k=3}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{a_k}\right).$$

If $a_k$ grows sufficiently, this product will converge, and we can apply our previous result (if not, we must find better bounds $f$ and $g$ - the verification that this product converges is left as an exercise). This gives that

$$\mu = 2+\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(a_{n+1})}{\ln(a_2)+\ln(a_3)+\cdots+\ln(a_n)}.$$

Taking $a_n=2^{2^n}$ gives

$$\mu = 2+\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{n+1}\ln(2)}{\sum_{k=2}^n \ln(2)2^{k}}$$

$$\mu = 2+\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}-8}$$

$$\mu = 3.$$

$\mu$ for other sequences can be derived similarly.

Comment: This means that $[4,16,256,65536,2^{32},\cdots ]$ must be transcendental, right ?

Comment: Can I always apply the limit given in the lower part of the answer assuming that the given limit exists ? Or are there additional restrictions ?

Comment: @Peter Which limit are you talking about?

Comment: The limit with $\ln(a_{n+1})$ , $\ln(a_2)$ and so on.

Comment: @Peter It should be OK. Also, be very, very careful with your indices - I believe you're off by one with your definition of $a$.